# JAVA 8 Memory/ collection/list values to be assigned from list to an object

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I am very new to Java Programming and hence is this query.
I have a class which defines the object with String, LocalDate, Boolean, Double. 
In my main, I have read from an input file. Using File, Lines, Path.
I am storing it in list.

how do I assign each value to each field in object definition?
Tried the following but getting error that its not defined as the type of String.

```
    package com.bapu;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.stream.*;

    public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
            String inputFileName = "e:/input/instruct.csv";     
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                list = Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFileName))
                .map(s -> s.trim())
                .skip(1)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());          
             } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
         }
         // list.forEach(System.out::println);      

            List<Instruction1> instruct1 = list.stream()
                    .map(p -> { 
                        Instruction1 instruct2 = new ClientInstructions(                        
                        instruct1.setClientName(p.getClientName()),
                        instruct1.setFlag(p.getFlag()), // etc etc......
                        //return instruct1; 
                        );  })                  
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } // main()
    } //class()

In another java file , I have the class object defined.
    package com.bapu;   
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    public class Instruction1 {

    private String clientName;
    private Boolean flag ;
    //  etc etc variables
    public Instruction1(String clName1, Boolean flag1.... ) {
        super();
        this.clientName= clName1;
        this.flag = flag1;
    } // argument Constructor

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
       }   
        /// all getters setters. followed hereafter
     }

    }  // class Instruction1
```

Not understanding the flow of information logic here.
Requesting for guidance.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're new to Java I'd suggest you stick to the basics first and skip the streaming api for now. Besides that please provide a [mcve], the code you posted tells us next to nothing.

Comment: Thomas is right, you should start understanding objects and the overall language structure and syntax. Here we see that sa example: `List<String> instruct1` is declaring a list of strings; `instruct1.setClientName(...)` is trying to set the client name **of that list** (`List` does not have that attribute). Probably wanted: `Instructions instr2  = new ClientInstructions(); instr2.setClientName(...)`

Comment: Yes. I am good at OOPS. I have studied core Java, Java 8, Sprint. So concepts are know. Using is something I am trying with simple examples and now stuck to this. I shall post the code snippet now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Instruction {
    private String clientName;
    private Boolean flag;

    public Instruction(String clientName, Boolean flag) {
        super();
        this.clientName = clientName;
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return String.format("ClientName : %s, Flag : %s", this.clientName,
                this.flag);
    }
}

public class App {

    static BiFunction<String, Boolean, Instruction> createInstrucationFn = (
            client, flag) -> new Instruction(client, flag);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String inputFileName = "e:/input/instruct.csv";

        List<String> dataLine = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(inputFileName));

        List<Instruction> instructionList = dataLine
                .stream()
                .map(line -> {
                    String[] pairs = line.split(",");
                    return createInstrucationFn.apply(pairs[0], Boolean.valueOf(pairs[1]));
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        instructionList.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

For this example File is assumed be like.

```
Client-A,true
Client-B,true
```

Output :

```
ClientName : Client-A, Flag : true
ClientName : Client-B, Flag : true
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. Got to know about BiFunction.  I am now trying to pass more arguments through my class Instructions. (with Date, float[] etc). Looks like BiFunction will not take them. While I am checking more on this, any further hint from your side is welcome.

Comment: @PriyamwadaveeraVasantgadkar Try out creating your own functional Interface specific to your requirement. Since you are new to this, I advise you to pick some books and follow that. 
This is good book to refer for Java 8 streaming and Multi-Threading concepts 
OCP Oracle(r) Certified Professional Java Programmer 2 - Jeanne Boyarsky